# Google Drive Form Data Validation

Tags: javascript, google-app-engine, google-drive-api

I'm working on a Google Drive Form that will validate input and send an email upon submission. The problem is attaching handlers to the Google created form controls. Some [tutorials](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/uiapp#Validators) create the controls and add them to an instance of UiApp and return that object from the function after attaching the handlers. I've tried calling a function like that on form open but it did not work, but I am able to call functions upon submission like this.

```
function sendFormByEmail(e) 
{ 
  var email = "some@email.com"; 
  var subject = "Form Results"; 
  var message = ""; for(var field in e.namedValues) 
  { 
    message += field + ' :: ' + e.namedValues[field].toString() + "\n\n";
  } 
  MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, message); 

}
```

However, I want to do client and server side validation. The thought came to my head that I'll just see what kind of attributes the html has for the controls and maybe I can find the controls that way, but I don't know that Google won't change the id, class, or name at any given time for that matter. Here's the code I tried to use last and return an instance of UiApp, but I'd much prefer to grab the contorls and have my way with them.

```
function doGet(){
  //create app
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  //controls
  var txtbAccountNumber = app.createTextBox().setId('tbAccountNumber').setName('tbnAccountNumber');
  var txtbOwnerEmail = app.createTextBox().setId('tbOwnerEmail').setName('tbnOwnerEmail');
  var txtbAccountAdjustment = app.createTextBox().setId('tbAccountAdjustment').setName('tbnAccountAdjustment');
  var btnSubmit = app.createButton("Submit").setEnabled(false);
  var lblEmailFailed = app.createLabel("The email was not valid");
  var lblAccountNumber = app.createLabel("The account number was not valid");
  var lblAccountAdjustment = app.createLabel("The account adjustment was not valid");
  //handler for submit click
  var handler = app.createServerHandler("validateInput")
  .validateEmail(txtbOwnerEmail)
  .validateNumber(txtbAccountNumber)
  .validateNumber(txtbAccountAdjustment)
  .addCallbackElement(txtbAccountNumber)
  .addCallbackElement(txtbOwnerEmail)
  .addCallbackElement(txtbAccountAdjustment);

  //callback control handlers
  var validEmail = app.createClientHandler()
  .validateEmail(txtbOwnerEmail)
  .forTargets(txtbOwnerEmail)
  .setStyleAttribute("color","black")
  .forTargets(btnSubmit)
  .setEnabled(true)
  .forTargets(lblEmailFailed)
  .setVisible(false);

  var validAccountNumber = app.createClientHandler()
  .validateNumber(txtbAccountNumber)
  .forTargets(txtbAccountNumber)
  .setStyleAttribute("color","black")
  .forTargets(btnSubmit)
  .setEnabled(true)
  .forTargets(lblAccountNumber)
  .setVisible(false);

  var validAccountAdjustment = app.createClientHandler()
  .validateNumber(txtbAccountAdjustment)
  .forTargets(txtbAccountAdjustment)
  .setStyleAttribute("color","black")
  .forTargets(btnSubmit)
  .setEnabled(true)
  .forTargets(lblAccountAdjustment)
  .setVisible(false);

  var invalidEmail = app.createClientHandler()
  .validateEmail(txtbOwnerEmail)
  .forTargets(txtbOwnerEmail)
  .setStyleAttribute("color","red")
  .forTargets(btnSubmit)
  .setEnabled(false)
  .forTargets(lblEmailFailed)
  .setVisible(true);

  var invalidAccountNumber = app.createClientHandler()
  .validateNumber(txtbAccountNumber)
  .forTargets(txtbAccountNumber)
  .setStyleAttribute("color","red")
  .forTargets(btnSubmit)
  .setEnabled(false)
  .forTargets(lblAccountNumber)
  .setVisible(true);

  var invalidAccountAdjustment = app.createClientHandler()
  .validateNumber(txtbAccountAdjustment)
  .forTargets(txtbAccountAdjustment)
  .setStyleAttribute("color","red")
  .forTargets(btnSubmit)
  .setEnabled(false)
  .forTargets(lblAccountAdjustment)
  .setVisible(true);

  txtbOwnerEmail.addBlurHandler(validEmail);
  txtbOwnerEmail.addBlurHandler(invalidEmail);
  txtbAccountNumber.addBlurHandler(validAccountNumber);
  txtbAccountNumber.addBlurHandler(invalidAccountNumber);
  txtbAccountAdjustment.addBlurHandler(validAccountAdjustment);
  txtbAccountAdjustment.addBlurHandler(invalidAccountAdjustment);
  btnSubmit.addClickHandler(handler);

  app.add(txtbOwnerEmail);
  app.add(txtbAccountNumber);
  app.add(txtbAccountAdjustment);
  app.add(lblEmailFailed);
  app.add(lblAccountNumber);
  app.add(lblAccountAdjustment);

  return app;
}

function validateInput(e){
 var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var pattern = /^[a-zA-Z0-9._]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9._]{2,4}/;
  return pattern.test(e.parameter.txtbOwnerEmail);   
}
```

How do I attach handlers and validate the fields to the Google Doc's generated forms?

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible. You'd have to create a form yourself using the UiApp or HtmlService. The only interaction that you can currently have with a Google Form is that you can bind to onFormSubmit().

Comment: Well, I do think it's possible but it would take a lot of extra Javascript and be somewhat of a hack.